# Evaluate a definite Integration problem

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1}(\sqrt[3]{1-x^7} - \sqrt[7]{1-x^3})dx$$

Comment: Your thoughts so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denoting $D\equiv x^7+y^3-1\le 0\;x\ge 0,y\ge 0$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sqrt[3]{1-x^7} - \sqrt[7]{1-x^3}\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{1-x^7}dx-\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[7]{1-y^3}dy$$ $$=\int_0^1dx\int_0^{\sqrt[3]{1-x^7}}dy-\int_0^1dy\int_0^{\sqrt[7]{1-y^3}}dx=\iint_Ddxdy-\iint_Ddxdy=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Consider the area in the first quadrant bounded by $x^7+y^3  = 1$.

Express this area in two ways:

(1) an integral with respect to $x$,

(2) an integral with respect to $y$.

These integrals must evaluate to the same number.

Answer (score 1):

Another method (using brute force):

$$I_1=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{1-x^7}dx\underbrace{=}_{t=x^7}\frac{1}{7}\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^{1/3}t^{-6/7}dt\underbrace{=}_{\text{Beta function}}\ldots$$ In a similar way

$$I_2=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[7]{1-x^3}dx\underbrace{=}_{t=x^3}\ldots=I_2.$$